# ajax: how to drag box and save location

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've a main div of which inside I've some more divs. I want the inner divs to be draggable inside the main div and when saved, saves their positions.
Can anyone help me on how to save the positions? [Permanently, not just for the current session]

Comment: Is this going to run locally, or on a server?  Also, when you mean save do you mean just stay where they were moved for the session or persisted in the same position?

Comment: right now working in localhost but will be deployed on a server later. I want it permanently saved, the positions; not just for the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

You can get the position of each div, fetching the left and top css attributes. You can see the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/position/ and use:

```
var obj = jQuery("#inner_div").position();
var coord_x = position.left;
var coord_y = position.top;
```

Finally, if you want to update some input you can do it adding a callback to the stop event of the draggable interaction of jQuery UI. Hope that helps!.

Comment: I think this should do but let me try out first before I accept it as a answer. Btw, where should I save the coordinates?? Should I save in a database ( I want it to be permanent, until edited again).